# Prevent Navlink from highlighting on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to have a whole section of a page act as a link to another page, but I don't want the section to be highlighted in blue when the user hovers over it. No matter what I do it highlights on hover.

JS

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
<NavLink to="/application" className="nohighlight">
          <h1 className="puppytitle">
           Get your own puppy 
           
          </h1>
        </NavLink>
```

CSS

I thought using !important was like the nuclear option for css, but even that is not working.

```
.nohighlight {
text-emphasis: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nohightlight:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What library are you pulling `<NavLink>` from?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that, it's from React-router-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you needed to do was define the color of the text. Here's an example:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Router>
          <StyledNavLink to='www.google.ca'>testing</StyledNavLink>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-emphasis: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  &:hover {
    text-emphasis: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
`;
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-63925598-navlink-color-gqop8

Comment: So it works in your codesandbox, but for some reason it doesn't work in my code. I changed it to be ``` <StyledNavLink to="/about">``` 
But the problem persists. Do you have any more ideas? 
The full code is here. the problem is in the "puppyseg" component
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-shtern-5jk8p

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp I've updated my answer with the styling you need. Just make sure you change the colour to `white` given your background, and remove the `className`s on the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags within your `<StyledNavLink>`, let me know if that helped!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem!! I'm happy to help!